# Adobe AEM/CQ5 personalizable carousel

Tags: aem

I am trying to build a carousel where a user can personalize each slide. Out of box carousel does not seem to do it.

The solution I end up doing was to extend the parsys and keep the virtual 3cols. I renamed the 3cols to carousel and added a custom attribute called renderType and set it to "carousel". So when parsys tries to render, knowing it is carousel I render as carousel instead of regular content holder.

It works but then I would like call a javascript when a user clicks "Preview" so that I can render this as carousel and when they unchoose "Preview" by clicking Edit or Target, I would render normally.

I see that you can listen to WCMMode change event but I am not able to get concrete e.g or documentation to perform. Any help?

Comment: Why don't you try to use the Slideshow component available OOTB rather than customizing so heavily?

Comment: What do you mean by _personalize each slide_? Is every slide supposed to be different depending on the user that views the carousel? If it's just about being able to manage every slide, perhaps it would be easier to create a separate configuration page with a normal paragraph system and load the content based on a simple configuration (some pathfield) in the actual carousel component. This would also allow you to reuse carousel content across pages.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz Author must be able to target each slide and specify different content based on client context. Thinking through your suggestion, are you suggesting have separate page for each slide and allow author to target the content on those page and then allow carousel to load those pages? Sorry, don't think I complete followed your suggestion.

Comment: @rakhi4110 Slideshow I tried today after you mentioned, not sure how well they support target each item. Any suggestion?

Comment: I had conversation with Adobe team and it is not out of box component that can support individual targeting. One suggestion was to have have different carousel for each campaign. It duplicates the content and could be nightmare of to maintain